# Symmetry of the Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) antibracket operation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, lie-algebra, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Batalin and Vilkovisky define $^1$ an operation they call antibracket which is

$$(F,H)
=
\Big(\frac{\partial_r F}{\partial \Phi^A}\Big)
\Big(\frac{\partial_l H}{\partial \Phi^* _A} \Big)
-
\Big(\frac{\partial_r F}{\partial \Phi^* _A}\Big)
\Big(\frac{\partial_l H}{\partial \Phi^A} \Big) \tag{0}
$$

where index $r$ and $l$ indicate respectively right and left derivative with respect to fields $\Phi$ and antifield $\Phi^*$.

This operation has some similar properties with super-Lie commutator such as Grassmann Parity

$$
 \epsilon[(F,H)] = \epsilon(F) + \epsilon(H) + 1\tag{1}
$$

and symmetry

$$
 (F,H) = -(-1)^{(\epsilon_F + 1)(\epsilon_H+1)}(H,F)\tag{2}
.$$

My question is about these properties. I am working on the way to prove them. I tried to use that $$FH = (-1)^{\epsilon_F\epsilon_H}HF\tag{3}$$ in second property but I didn't get to the right answer.

--

$^1$ I. A. Batalin and G. A. Vilkovisky, Phys. Lett. B102 (1981) 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fun fact: Eqs. (1) & (2) can be intuitively understood via the [Koszul sign rule/convention](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=koszul+sign) as that the comma in the [antibracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerstenhaber_algebra) (0) is Grassmann-odd/Fermionic $|,|=1$. E.g. the parity for permuting $F   \leftrightarrow ","\leftrightarrow H$ in eq. (2) is then after some [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)$^1$
   $$|F||H| + |F||,| +|H||,| ~=~|F||H| + |F| +|H| ~=~ (|F|+1)(|H|+1)+1. \tag{A}$$
   Of course eq. (A) is only a pseudo-explanation. Let's now turn to an actual proof.
2. *Sketched proof of eq. (2):* Use the following rules:
   $$ |\Phi^{\ast}_A|~=~|\Phi^A|+1~:=~|A|+1, \tag{B}$$
   and
   $$ \frac{\partial^LF}{\partial z}~=~(-1)^{(|F|+1)|z|}\frac{\partial^RF}{\partial z}. \tag{C}$$
   So e.g. the parity for permuting the first term
   $$ \frac{\partial^RF}{\partial \Phi^A}\frac{\partial^LH}{\partial \Phi^{\ast}_A}  \leftrightarrow  \frac{\partial^RH}{\partial \Phi^{\ast}_A}\frac{\partial^LF}{\partial \Phi^A}\tag{D}$$ 
   in the antibracket (0) is
   $$ \underbrace{\overbrace{(|F|+|A|)(|H|+|A|+1)}^{\text{rule } (3)}
   }_{=~(|F|+|H|)|A|+|F|(|H|+1)} 
   +\underbrace{\overbrace{(|F|+1)|A|}^{\text{rule } (C)} 
   +\overbrace{(|H|+1)(|A|+1)}^{\text{rule } (C)}
   }_{=~(|F|+|H|)|A|+(|H|+1)}
   ~=~(|F|+1)(|H|+1).\tag{E}$$
   Note that the rhs. (E) does not depend on $|A|$ (as it shouldn't!), and that the rhs. (E) is opposite the sought-for result (A). This explains the relative sign between the 2 terms in the antibracket (0). 
   $\Box$

--

$^1$ In this answer we use 
$$|\cdot|~\equiv~ \epsilon(\cdot)~\in~ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}~\cong~\{0,1\} \tag{F}$$ 
to denote Grassmann-parity.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, it was really usefull.